# averaging numbers on a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

Suppose you have $n$ numbers $a_1, \dots, a_n$ arranged on a circle. You replace each number with the average of its neighbors, i.e, you replace $a_1$ with $\frac{a_n+a_2}{2}$, and $a_2$ with $\frac{a_1+a_3}{2}$, and so on. If you do this sufficiently many times will the numbers be roughly equal?

Giving a negative answer for even $n$ is not hard, but I'm interested in a careful analysis of the problem. I can prove that the matrix of this operation, say $A$, is diagonalizable and has eigenvalues $\lambda_k=\cos(2\pi k/n)$ for $k=0, 1, \dots, n-1$. So in the case that $n$ is odd all eigenvalues satisfy $|\lambda_k|<1$ except for $\lambda_0=1$. And when $n$ is even, $k=n/2$ gives the eigenvalue $-1$.

What would be a good strategy to finish the solution from here? (Feel free to suggest a different method if you prefer...)

Note: This appears as a "baby problem" in Kirillov's [notes](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kirillov/mat552/liegroups.pdf) (page 7) on Lie groups but the solution he gives is not quite complete.

Comment: Probabilistic version: if we do a nearest-neighbor simple random walk $(X_i)_{i\ge 1}$ on $\Bbb Z/(n)$, then from any starting measure, will the law of $X_i$ converge to the uniform measure as $i \to \infty$?

Comment: For even values of $n$, an easy counterexample is given by alternating $1's$ and $0's$. This reflects the periodicity of the Markov chain. When $n$ is odd, the chain is irreducible and aperiodic, so yes, it will converge to the invariant measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix of the operation, $A$, is symmetric, and thus has orthogonal eigenvectors. Define $q_i$ as the $i$th eigenvector. Let $u_0$ be the vectorized version of the initial set of numbers: $u_0 := [a_1 \; a_2 \; \dots \; a_n]$ . We can express $u_0$ in terms of $q_i$ as 
\begin{align*}
u_0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i q_i.
\end{align*}
for some $\alpha_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$. Then application of the operation $A$ $k$ times would give the vector
\begin{align*}
u_k=A^k u_0 = A^k \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i q_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i A^k q_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \lambda_i^k q_i,
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $A$.

Next, note that $\mathbf{1}$ (all ones vector) is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue 1 since $A\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$.

For $n$ odd, since all $\lambda_i$'s except one (say $\lambda_0$) satisfy $|\lambda_i|<1$ (and therefore $\lambda_i^k \to 0$), we have that
\begin{align*}
u_k \to \lambda_0^k \alpha_0q_0 = \alpha_0 \mathbf{1},
\end{align*}
which shows the desired result. When $n$ is even, we have
\begin{align*}
u_k \to \alpha_0 \mathbf{1} + (-1)^k \alpha_n q_n,
\end{align*}
where $q_n$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue -1. Hence for $n$ even the second term causes oscillation.

Comment: Thanks! This is a variation of a solution that I had in mind (but without introducing an explicit orthogonal basis): One can show directly that $u:=\lim u_k$ is convergent when $n$ is odd and it is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$. I wonder if your solution implies that the entries of $u=\lim u_k$ are all equal to the average of $a_1, \dots, a_n$. (We already know that they are all equal but does the solution reveal the common value?)

Comment: Yes. Since the eigenvectors are orthogonal, $\alpha_0$ is essentially a projection of the $u_0$ vector onto $q_0$; and since the normalized version of $q_0$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbf{1}$, we have $\alpha_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} u_0^\top \mathbf{1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_i a_i$, and so $\alpha_0 \mathbf{1} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i a_i$. So it converges to the average of the numbers when $n$ is odd.